# How does Node.js improve scalability?

Tags: node.js

I have an HTTP Server created using Node.js. When it gets a request, it goes to the DB, fetches some data and gives it back to the Response object. The DB call is async and hence a single thread is able to handle a large number of concurrent connections.

But now that means a large number of requests operating concurrently, causing a potential choke at the DB. Though the web server is able to handle concurrent requests, the DB layer is not.

This must be a common problem for several web apps written using Node.js. Why then should I use Node.js for scalability?

Thanks,
Yash

Comment: This is really a question about how to design and run a high availability database -- nothing about node.js at all

Comment: Is is the DB access layer or the DB itself? This sounds very complex, but the issue is not necessarily caused by node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Well, main reason is that DB will choke much later than if you'd use sync web app and som other web server. Databases are much more powerful than webservers like Apache.

What ou have decribed is a common scalability problem. You will **always** have a bottleneck. Sometimes it's web app not concurent and efficient enough, sometimes it's database. You can scale database by creating replication cluster or other techniques valid for our choosen DB. You can also add new node.js servers if you need to.

Bottomline is that you have choosen more efficient web app server, so you might choke somewhere else and have to deal with that poblem. But you are still able to process more requests than you were before.

Comment: I understand that there will be a choking point sometime or the other. But why will an efficient web server like node.js postpone it? A query going to the DB is the same, no matter which web server you use. It will occupy the DB resources, lock certain tables, etc. Apache will block for the query to return. Node.js will not. But that would not change anything on the DB side. Am I missing something?

Comment: @yash it's called clustering. your db should be able to do it.

Comment: @Yash also, there are many concurrency models that you can utilize to get rid of locks, for example you can read dirty data or not lock table for `SELECT` operations.

Comment: I know there are several standard ways to prevent bottleneck in the DB. My main question is: How does Node.js help in delaying the bottleneck?

Comment: @Yash it's architecture is done for high concurency because of those async calls. You can read up on Reactor pattern.